# How can I temporarily disable a LocalDB database for connection failure testing?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, localdb

For developer testing, I run a LocalDB version of my SQLServer database from Visual Studio 2013. I want to test what happens when this database becomes unreachable to my C# application running on the same machine - ideally debugging from VS. Specifically, becomes unreachable while the application is running, so I can "turn it on/of" without re-starting my application and check it handles this OK.

I can't see an obvious "stop DB" option within VS. I also don't know how the LocalDB instance is managed... if it only exists while VS is running for instance?

What way(s) are there to do what I want, with both DB and application running on the same machine and the DB hosted as LocalDB not through SQLServer (which I don't have installed)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stopping the database you can just change the configuration to some dummy IP/Host or port in your connection string.

Comment: Not while the application is running. I specifically need to test the case the DB is lost for a specific period and is then reachable again.

Comment: You can find a process in task manager for the sql server. Kill that process

Comment: Or in cmd, net start SQLAgent$ instancename, you can use start,pause,stop too.

Comment: I found SQlservr.exe in task manager but even if I close VS first, whenever my application tries to contact the DB this process reappears after I kill it. And while I have a bunch of SQL Server services, none appear to be running. Unsure what is 'watching'

Answer (score 0):

LocalDB isn't ideal for testing of this scenario.  Better test on the real thing.

However, if you are just prototyping something, you could:

1. Start by testing how the application responds if you kill its database connection.  The app will get error code 596 (or perhaps 233).
2. Test how the app responds to `sqllocaldb stop <instancename> -k`
   (it will probably be seeing an error code 904 or 109; it's a poor test as the localdb will be automatically restarted nearly immediately).
3. Make sure, perhaps by source code inspection, that the application is similarly impervious to error code -2, -1, or 2, which is what you will probably be seeing in regular disconnections or when recovering from those.

While I have listed some error codes I have seen, because the app you are testing (or its library) might be doing something like that, I don't really recommend coding against individual error codes.  A disconnection is better detected as an error with severity 20 or more.

Don't forget to do the final testing in conditions similar to your production conditions.